# testimonials section not displaying after uploading to subdomain

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a bootstrap website on a local drive. After uploading to subdomain to test it out, the testimonials section does not display. It should appear just under the pricing plans section. Any ideas?  subdomain is http://watermanlandscaping.minormedia.ca/index.html#home   ...many thanks

Answer (score 0):

CSS display property for .owl-carousel class is **NONE**, change it and it will work ! :)

Apperance --> Theme Options --> Custom CSS:

```
.owl-carousel{
display:block;
}
```